# Mismatch in timing

Tags: c++, timing, strftime, timeval

```
struct timeval start, end, duration;
gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
timersub(&end, &start, &duration);

tm* startTime = localtime(&start.tv_sec);
tm* endTime = localtime(&end.tv_sec);
char buf[64];
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", startTime);
char buf2[64];
strftime(buf2, sizeof(buf2), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", endTime);

ofstream timeFile;
timeFile.open ("timingSheet.txt");
timeFile << fixed << showpoint;
timeFile << setprecision(6);
timeFile << "Duration: " << duration.tv_sec << "." << duration.tv_usec << " seconds \n";
timeFile << "Start time: " <<  buf <<"." << start.tv_usec << "\n";
timeFile << "End time: " <<  buf2 <<"." << end.tv_usec << "\n";
timeFile.close();
```

When I run this code I get this output:

```
Duration: 3.462243 seconds 
Start time: 2012-05-15 17:14:07.432613
End time: 2012-05-15 17:14:07.894856
```

What puzzles me is that the duration value doesn't match up with the Start and End times. The two dates only differ by the micro seconds. Is there a reason for this?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens in `timersub()`?

Comment: timersub() shouldn't affect either start or end. It is simply a function for getting the difference in two timevals and placing those values in duration.

Comment: Please post the code.  If it doesn't alter `start` or `end`, then it must calculate `duration` incorrectly.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/timersub I'm not sure where the code actually is.

Comment: `# define timersub(a, b, result)            \
  do {               \
    (result)->tv_sec = (a)->tv_sec - (b)->tv_sec;         \
    (result)->tv_usec = (a)->tv_usec - (b)->tv_usec;         \
    if ((result)->tv_usec < 0) {           \
      --(result)->tv_sec;            \
      (result)->tv_usec += 1000000;           \
    }               \
  } while (0)
#endif /* BSD */
`

Comment: Interesting you are precisely 1 second out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localtime return a statically allocated buffer and you call it twice ,so StartTime and EndTime are the same. You need to copy it in another buffer directcly after each call.

```
tm* startTime = localtime(&start.tv_sec); 
char buf[64]; 
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", startTime); 

tm* endTime = localtime(&end.tv_sec); 
char buf2[64]; 
strftime(buf2, sizeof(buf2), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", endTime);
```

EDIT: you can also write this:

```
tm* pTimeBuf = localtime(&start.tv_sec); 
char buf[64]; 
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", pTimeBuf); 

localtime(&end.tv_sec); // NB. I don't store th return value (since I have it already)
char buf2[64]; 
strftime(buf2, sizeof(buf2), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", pTimeBuf);
```

Comment: the problem is not with strftime() ,it's with localtime(). localtime returns a pointer to an internal piece of memory. That memory is reused with every call to localtime. your variables starttime en endtime have the same pointervalue ,in fact you could get rid of one (I will update my answer so you can see what I mean).

Comment: the safer and undoubtly better variant of localtime() is the one pointed out by AwesomeNix's answer.

Comment: recently download this (don't remember from where) and currently reading it : The Linux Programming Interface - A Linux and UNIX System Programming Handbook (No Starch, 2010, 1593272200).pdf

Comment: Interesting that they would implement it like that. I'm using this and my answer makes much more sense, but still is off! I got these results: `Duration: 2.759294 seconds 
Start time: 2012-05-16 13:12:41.39434
End time: 2012-05-16 13:12:43.798728`
I'm testing to see if I get more consistent results if I don't use timersub.

Comment: @Dave : I think the display of the tv_usecs is not correct. 41.39434 should be displayed as 41.039434

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Edwin here, just a minor modification that its better to use the thread safe version [localtime_r](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/localtime.html) instead of localtime

```
struct tm startTime,endTime;
memset(&startTime,0,sizeof(struct tm)); //Advisable but not necessary
memset(&endTime,0,sizeof(struct tm)); //Advisable but not necessary
localtime_r(&start.tv_sec, &startTime);
localtime_r(&end.tv_sec, &endTime);
```